# Fade Out Text At Bottom of Page Based on Position in a Web Page

Tags: html

There is a cool effect where the bottom of the page seems to fade out located at the following link

https://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeOutBottom/

Can someone please show me how to incorporate the tool into my website.

I'm serious a novice to css and not sure where to begin with this - which is why I'm looking for a ready made tool.

Your help will be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: Being a novice is not a good reason not to try something yourself before asking. Please make some research and provide the code you tried. This is the reason why some guys have already downvoted your question which in fact doesn't sound as question at all (it sounds "do some coding for me").

Comment: Ok. I'll try, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: I have updated this question with the answer I discovered from Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

It's a trick using a PNG file called 'bottom-fade.png' which is a gradient from full transparent at the top to opaque white at the end. Now that the background is white, it gives a feeling of the text fading out. The image is put in a layer which is set always forward (check z-index) and with fixed position (meaning it will always be at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Hi Berdiya, thanks for responding. As I mentioned, I'm absolute novice to this, but I created a website with Joomla and would like to incorporate this file or feature in my pages. Can you help please please

Comment: OK, community, I have found the code located here that I think will achieve what I'm after. The only problem is I'm not sure where to place it. Its JQuery. Please note, I'm not asking you to do any work for me, just let me know where to place it. https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

Comment: OK, I have been doing some reading and just placing the jquery code isn't enough. I will continue doing more research before someone from this community screams at me again.

Comment: Ok, the JQuery is too much for me to understand. Therefore, I'm going refocus my efforts with the files at the link I provided above https://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeOutBottom/.  All I ask is that some let me know what to do with the files ?

Comment: Can someone just let me know how the html file is generated.

Answer (score 1):

After much delibertation I managed to achieve this using Animate.css library for animating the fade

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */

$(window).scroll( function(){

/* Check the location of each desired element */
$('.hideme').each( function(i){

    var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();


    /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
    if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    }    else {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
               }

}); 
}); 
});
```

I hope this help others with a similar problem